# load native library from library

Tags: java, c, tomcat, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am hosting a Java web application on Tomcat7 in Ubuntu.

I have a main shared .so library which depends on a native library. The main library gets loaded, but I get an error when it tries to load it's native library. Basically the main library is a JNI wrapper around the native library.

`lib_mynative_lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

Both the main library and native library are in the same location. What could possibly be the problem here? Isn't it possible to load a library from a library? Are there some other hidden PATH definitions that I must declare for Tomcat? The first library was picked up, but no the second.

---

EDIT:

Giving this more thought, it sounds logical that Tomcat will need to know where the main library is, therefore I specified it in `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh` as

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/home/me/my_shared_lib"
```

This works for the main library.

Now, for the native library I added the following to the same setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS "-Djava.library.path=/home/me/my_shared_lib"
```

But no change.

More info: 
The first (main) library is loaded from Java with `System.loadLibrary("lib_mymainlib.so")`, while the the second library is loaded in C++ code with `dlopen("lib_mynative_lib.so", 1)`.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how you're loading the second library. Are you using an absolute or relative path?

Comment: @JornVernee I have edited the question; please see above.

Comment: Oh I am using a relative path. Example: load("lib_mynative_lib.so")

Comment: But that is the path relative to the first library right? It should be relative to the working directory. i.e. if you load the first library with something like ```load("libs/lib_somelib.so")```, the second one should be loaded with ```load("lib/lib_mynative_lib.so")```. But if you use ```System.loadLibrary``` instead, that will use ```java.library.path```.

Comment: The first library is loaded in Java with System.loadLibrary("lib_mymainlib.so"). The second library is loaded in C++ with load("lib_mynative_lib.so"). Both libraries are in the same folder. No sub-directories.

Comment: ```load``` requires an absolute path though.

Comment: @JornVernee The first (main) library is loaded from Java with `System.loadLibrary("lib_mymainlib.so")`, while the the second library is loaded in C++ code with `dlopen("lib_mynative_lib.so", 1)`.